# How to get value from onPaste event in TextField on Flutter when the copied value is more than TextField maxLength?

Tags: flutter, material-ui, textfield

I have a Flutter `TextField` widget as below:

```
class DummyPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const DummyPage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<DummyPage> createState() =>
      _DummyPageState();
}

class _DummyPageState extends ConsumerState<DummyPage> {
  final TextEditingController _controllers =TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    final form = ref.read(formStateProvider);
    
    _controllers.text = form ?? "";

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllers.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: _controllers,
      maxLength: 10,
      onChanged: (val) {
        log(val, name: "Form Change");
        ref.read(formStateProvider.notifier).change(index, val);
      },
    )
  }
}
```

I know that one way to detect the onPaste event is by using `onChanged` properties, but if the length of the copied value is more than 10, it will only copy 10 first char of the copied value then I will only get the 10 first char (since the max length is set to 10). So, how to get the full value even if the copied value is more than 10 (if the copied value is 20 char length, I will still get the 20 char length and not only the first 10 char)?

Comment: Could you clarify what are you trying to achieve or provide an example step by step?

Comment: You can save the value you get from `onPaste` event in some variable and then decide what you want to do, but your `TextField` has clear instruction that `maxLength` is 10 and therefore you cannot "write" more than 10 characters into it.
Workaround would be to develop your own `TextField` widget inherited from the provided one and then make some tweaks in `maxLength` property. The idea what you want to achieve is not fully clear tbh.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to have a numeric code verification form that consists of a `List<TextField>`, and each of them has `maxLength = 1`. The expected behavior is when there is a paste event on the first element (`List<TextField>[0]`), I will set the copied value across all items in `List<TextField>`.

Comment: So how to handle the case?